# .net core 3 status code 405 in response when using httpClient and Fiddler?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-3.1

Why am I getting status code 405 in response when using httpClient or Fiddler?
I am getting a status code 405 response when tyring to access a net core 3.1 wepapi action method that accepts json string sent in the body as shown below.
The status code 405 occurs when the request is sent in a net core 3.1 console app using httpClient.
In Fiddler the request works fine.
The webapi action code is

```
[RequireHttps]
        [HttpPut("setkdatainformation/{id:int:min(0):max(5)}/{info}")]
       [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<string> SetKDataInformation(int id,  string info, [FromBody] string kinfo)
        {
```

The request is sent from a .net core 3.1 console app using http client as shown below

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(newMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue($"application/json"));        
 var dData = $"{q}kdata test{q}";
  var content = new StringContent(dData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(${url}api/v1.0/KDataServer/setkdatainformation/{connectionId}/{headerLoginName}", content);
```

Comment: I added to the startup the enableing of coors. But the problem still persists.  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseCors(builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            });

Comment: CORS issue would not cause [**405 Method Not Allowed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).

Answer (score 0):

> The status code 405 occurs when the request is sent in a net core 3.1 console app using httpClient.

I did a test based on the code snippet you shared, which work well on my side. If possible, you can try to create a new project and create controller with only this action method then test if it can work well.

```
var q = "\"";
var connectionId = 2;
var headerLoginName = "test";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue($"application/json"));
var dData = $"{q}kdata test{q}";
var content = new StringContent(dData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync($"https://xxxx/setkdatainformation/{connectionId}/{headerLoginName}", content);
```

[image]

> In Fiddler the request works fine

You mentioned the request could be processed fine if you make it via fiddler, to troubleshoot the issue, you can capture the request that you sent from console app using fiddler, then compare the request url, header(s) and body etc with that working one you sent through fiddler and make sure you are making request(s) to same endpoint from both fiddler and console app.